# Nemiver: при отладке rand() вылезает ошибка

Tags: c++, geany

При отладке функции rand() вылезает ошибка:
Не удалось найти файл /build/glibc-LK5gWL/glibc-2.23/stdlib/random.c

При нажатии Отмена вылезает другое сообщение: Не удалось найти файл rand.c

IDE - Geany

Comment: В общем-то, отладчик предназначен для отладки в первую очередь ваших программ, а не системных функций, поэтому их исходный код не входит в состав IDE

Comment: я отлаживал програму, когда дошел до строки с rand() вылезло сообщение

Comment: В IDE обычно бывают разные шаги отладки, что-то типа step into и прочих. Вам не нужно пытаться «входить» в строку, в которой происходит вызов «чужой» функции. Код `rand` для Вас недоступен, поэтому и отлаживать там нечего. По конкретной IDE не подскажу, т.к. впервые слышу о подобной, но в той же Visual Studio отладка всегда по умолчанию выполняется через Step Over (F10).

Comment: Спасибо, в Geany я нашел кнопку перешагивать через инструкции asm. Не могу понять как настроить по умолчанию чтобы перешагивало через asm